# Instantiate a module in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, salesforce

I am using a third party library (gem) to instantiate two versions of the same Class. The gem's documentation instantiates the Class

```
client.sobject_module = My::Module
client.materialize("Contact") #=> My::Module::Contact
```

And my code does this.

```
client.sobject_module = MyModule
client.materialize("Contact")
```

The module itself is empty

```
module MyModule 
end
```

There are two versions of the same code, yet when I do

```
MyModule::Contact.find("John")
```

for instance it appears the Contact got materialed into the global namespace. This is a materialize method that gets called from the gem

```
def materialize(classnames)
  classes = (classnames.is_a?(Array) ? classnames : [classnames]).collect do |clazz|
    original_classname = clazz
    clazz = original_classname[0,1].capitalize + original_classname[1..-1]
    unless const_defined_in_module(module_namespace, clazz)
      new_class = module_namespace.const_set(clazz,  Class.new(Databasedotcom::Sobject::Sobject))
      new_class.client = self
      new_class.materialize(original_classname)
      new_class
    else
      module_namespace.const_get(clazz)
    end
  end
  classes.length == 1 ? classes.first : classes
end
```

client on the new_class appears to get set correctly, but when I do

```
MyModule::Contact.client
```

it returns the same client as

```
MyModule1::Contact.client
```

I have spent days trying to figure this out any pointers will be helpful. The gem I am using is [this](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just released a wrapper around the gem that let's you walk around this issue.
It works kinda like:

```
Databasedotcom::Isolated.perform(options) do
  # Constants are materialized automatically
  contact = Contact.last  

  # Work with them as needed
  puts contact.inspect
end

# And everything get's cleaned up behind you.
defined? Contact # => nil
```

It's currently on an early stage but I hope it suit's your needs.
The source is available at https://github.com/sagmor/databasedotcom-isolated

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to summarise all my research in this area after banging my head for hours on this issue (a year later).

Unfortunately this is an outstanding bug in the databasedotcom gem. The issue is, currently the sfdc client is a class variable rather than a class *instance* variable so our materialized objects get shared between clients!

It is discussed in detail in issues [63](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/pull/63) and [73](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/73). You have several options from here:

1. Use the [monkey patch](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/pull/63#issuecomment-25131592)
2. Use the pull requests for the above issues
3. Use the [databasedotcom-isolate gem](https://github.com/sagmor/databasedotcom-isolated)
4. Throw out databsedotcom and use the new [restforce gem](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce) which is built to handle multiple sfdc orgs.

I'm going with the monkey patch for the moment as it is the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [bug](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/pull/63) in the databasedotcom gem. You can address the issue by adding a monkey patch in your initializer file

```
# config/initializers/databasedotcom.rb
Databasedotcom::Sobject::Sobject.class_attribute :client
```